# Missing module pyexpat for launching JupyterLab after updating Anaconda

Tags: conda, updates, jupyter-lab, anaconda3

After updating anaconda last version with
`conda update -n base`
Jupyter lab launched from an environment (called md) doesnt start anymore.
`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\md\Scripts\jupyter-lab-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    from jupyterlab.labapp import main
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\md\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labapp.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .extensions import MANAGERS as EXT_MANAGERS
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\md\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .pypi import PyPIExtensionManager
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\md\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\pypi.py", line 13, in <module>
    import xmlrpc.client
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\md\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 138, in <module>
    from xml.parsers import expat
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\md\Lib\xml\parsers\expat.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pyexpat import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing pyexpat: The specified module could not be found.
```

I later update the env md too but it reports the same error again. It seems that a module pyexpat is missing. The jupyter lab is also missing in the Anaconda Navigator's window of the env md.
If I launch JL from base (root) it starts.
I update the navigator too but the situation isnt changed.
How can I solve this?